# Add CSS every 0.3 seconds iterate through all items (unlimited amount)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page which displays any number of items (could be 1, could be 50).

At the moment, each `.job-item` is set to `opacity:0;` on load.

I'd like to make each of these items change to `opacity:1` with a 0.3 second gap between each.

How can I do this with jQuery? I know that I can create a `setInterval` for every 0.3 seconds as such:

```
setInterval(function(){
   alert("Hello");
}, 300);
```

But I do not know how to make the following line apply to each element. I also know there is `.each()` but I'm not sure how I would make this select through every item on the page? And at the separate intervals?

The code to be applied every 0.3 seconds on each item would be:

```
$('.job-item').css('opacity','1');
```

So I guess I'm looking for help combining `setInterval`, `.each()` and my `.css()` code.

This is the code I have so far. It makes every item show at .3s, rather than each item. I am not iterating properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $(".job-item").each(function() {
                $(this).css('opacity','1');
            });
        }, 300);
    });
```

Comment: You want the `.job-item` items to appear randomly or in a given order? ie.: From top-bottom or element 10, then, 27, then 2, etc. ?

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/6r8t4o0v/2/ ?

Comment: @Pobe in the given order. So when page loads, first instance of `.job-item` is opacity:1;. After 0.3s, second item has CSS applied etc until complete. My code example is close I believe but I am not iterating through each item correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function recursively

```
var jobItem = $('.job-item').css('opacity', '0')
var len = jobItem.length;
animate(0)

function animate(index) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jobItem.eq(index).css('opacity', '1');
        if (index < len) animate(++index) // call the function recursive
    }, 300)
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pg0k4t0d/)**

Comment: @downvoter Please put a command for your downvote ,You are doing good job without command that is not use

Comment: I like the recursive part of this. Rarely see this in jQuery. Nicely done.

Comment: @Pobe  Thanks for giving words :)